# Bunifu Framework "Text Box" SelectAll function missing?

Tags: c#, bunifu

Click on the Bunifu Framework TextBox then how can call the "SelectAll()" function? Because I want to select all text in the TextBox. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick fix

```
//replace (Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuMaterialTextbox) with your specified type of textbox   
 private void SelectAll(Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuMaterialTextbox metroTextbox)

            {
                foreach (var ctl in metroTextbox.Controls)
                {

                    if (ctl.GetType() == typeof(TextBox))

                    {
                        var txt = (TextBox)ctl;
                        txt.SelectAll();

                    }

                }

            }
```

Comment: Hey, You are always helping me.So, you are the best. Thanks a lot.